# What's the meaning of "hasta" in the following sentences?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

What's the meaning of "**hasta**" in the following sentences?

- Hasta que te dignes a hacerme caso.
- Los resultados del examen se publicarán hasta febrero.

Those have different meanings than the "hasta" of the following sentence:

- Hasta (incluso) un niño lo comprende.

Comment: The second sentence I should write like: "Los resultados del examen no se publicarán sino hasta febrero". What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost everything is explained by the [entry for "hasta" of the "Diccionario panhispánico de dudas"](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?clave=hasta&origen=RAE).

The first two sentences are explained by the first paragraph of the aforementioned entry:

> **hasta. 1**. Preposición que se usa para expresar el término límite en relación con el tiempo, el espacio o la cantidad.
>
> > Preposition used to express the limit related to time, space or amount of something.

Your last sentence is explained by the third paragraph of the aforementioned entry:

> **hasta. 3**. Puede funcionar como adverbio con el sentido de ‘incluso’ y, en ese caso, es compatible con otras preposiciones
>
> > May work as an adverb in the sense of "incluso", and in this case it is compatible with some other prepositions.

---

**Comment**:
In order to make your first example clearer, I would rewrite it to something like this:

- No te dejaré salir hasta que te dignes a hacerme caso.